# Python error calculating program

Tags: python, loops

Ask the user to enter payroll information for the company.  Set up a loop that continues to ask for information until they enter “DONE”.  For each employee ask three questions:

name (first & last)
hours worked this week (only allow 1 through 60)
hourly wage (only allow 6.00 through 20.00)
VALIDATE the hours worked and the hourly wage, and make sure a name is entered.

Calculate each employee’s pay, and write it out to a sequential file.   Be sure to include file I/O error handling logic.

Include only the weekly pay
Weekly pay is calculated: 
For (1-40 hours) it is hourly rate * hours worked
For (41-60 hours) it is (hours worked – 40) * (hourly rate * 1.5) 
+ hourly rate * 40

After all the employees are entered, read in the sequential file into a list named PAY for the weekly pay of each employee.  Sort the list.  Now print the lowest, highest, and average weekly pay for the week.

I am having obvious problem with this code

```
while len(eName)>0:
     eName=raw_input("\nPlease enter the employees' first and last name. ")
     hWork=raw_input("How many hours did they work this week? ")
     hoursWork=int(hWork)
     if hoursWork < 1 or hoursWork > 60:
         print "Employees' can't work less than 1 hour or more than 60 hours!"

     else:
         pRate=raw_input("What is their hourly rate? ")
         payRate=int(pRate)
         if payRate < 6 or payRate > 20:
              print "Employees' wages can't be lower than $6.00 or greater than $20.00!"
         if hoursWork <=40:
              grossPay=hoursWork*payRate
         else:
              grossPay=((hoursWork-40)*(payRate*1.5))+(40*payRate)
         lsthours.append(grossPay)
     print grossPay
     print lsthours



     ePass=raw_input("Type DONE when finished with employees' information. ")
     ePass.upper() == "DONE"
     if ePass == "DONE":
          break
     else:
          continue
```

Comment: The indentation of this looks totally wrong.  This might be a cut'n'paste problem - if so you need to edit so it looks how you really wrote it.  Otherwise Python won't do what you think it will,

Comment: I guess you need to correct indentation first. The current indentation suggests that "ePass = raw_input.." is out of while loop.

Comment: Is this homework? This kind of UI was common in 1980, but is not acceptable today for a deployed application.

Comment: yes this is homework,  I have been stuck for about a week so I am hoping to find some help.  I am not very comfortable using functions yet since we just started doing the a week ago.  I am open to any suggestions and help.  I am just not very familiar with the lingo so please have it dumbed down for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
lsthours = list()
eName = "start" # initialize to something to start the loop
while eName:
    eName = raw_input("\nPlease enter the employees' first and last name. ")
    if not eName:
        break #loop will exit also when blank name is inserted
    hWork = raw_input("How many hours did they work this week? ")
    hoursWork = int(hWork)
    if hoursWork < 1 or hoursWork > 60:
        print "Employees' can't work less than 1 hour or more than 60 hours!"
        continue #skip

    pRate = raw_input("What is their hourly rate? ")
    payRate = int(pRate)
    if payRate < 6 or payRate > 20:
        print "Employees' wages can't be lower than $6.00 or greater than $20.00!"
        continue #skip
    if hoursWork <= 40:
        grossPay = hoursWork * payRate
    else:
        grossPay = ((hoursWork - 40) * (payRate * 1.5)) + (40 * payRate)
    lsthours.append(grossPay)
    print grossPay
    print lsthours
    ePass = raw_input("Type DONE when finished with employees' information. ")
    if ePass.upper() == "DONE":
        break
```

It still lacks exception checking but should work.

The "data error" checks should just short-circuit the main loop, it's simpler, but you can have a more involved code and put them into their own loop.

Comment: Thanks that helped me a ton appreciate it so much

Comment: if I want to go on from here and do my reading and writing to a file will that break impeed it or will it continue to that part of my code

Comment: how do I add this to it:After all the employees are entered, read in the sequential file into a list named PAY for the weekly pay of each employee. Sort the list. Now print the lowest, highest, and average weekly pay for the week.

Comment: The `break` only stops the `while` loop. In python, indentation is everything, so you can rely on it to understand the workflow. In this case, the break and continue keywords apply to the most internal loop you're in, the `while eName`.

Comment: For the sort and output, do it before writing to the file. For file output, you should consider using the `csv` package. If you need to write to the file the employee's name too, then you should store in the list `lsthours` also the employee name, like in `lsthours.append([eName, grossPay])`. The max, min, sum, average etc can be obtained by intelligent use of list comprehension, like in `max_wage = max([item[1] for item in lsthours])`.

Comment: I appended the name to the list to how do i get it to print on a  new line

Answer (score 2):

There's several problems with this code:

- The indentation is all over the place.  For example, the while loop ends at that first if statement
- The test for the while loop is almost certainly false (since eName isn't initialised), so the loop never enters
- the code at ePass.upper() == "DONE" is trying to set the ePass variable, which means that test won't work.  You need:

  if ePass.upper() == "DONE":
       break

Answer (score 1):

Yu can do something as this:

```
grossPay = 0.0
lsthours = []

eName=raw_input("\nPlease enter the employees' first and last name (type 'PASS' to  exit): ") 

while eName.upper() != "PASS":      
   hWork=raw_input("How many hours did they work this week? ") 
   hoursWork=int(hWork)

   if hoursWork < 1 or hoursWork > 60: 
      print "Employees' can't work less than 1 hour or more than 60 hours!" 
   else: 
      pRate=raw_input("What is their hourly rate? ") 
      payRate=int(pRate) 

      if payRate < 6 or payRate > 20: 
         print "Employees' wages can't be lower than $6.00 or greater than $20.00!" 

      if hoursWork <=40: 
         grossPay=hoursWork*payRate 
      else: 
         grossPay=((hoursWork-40)*(payRate*1.5))+(40*payRate) 

      lsthours.append(grossPay) 

      print grossPay 
      print lsthours 

  eName=raw_input("\nPlease enter the employees' first and last name. (type 'PASS' to exit): ")
```

Comment: I need to have 3 loops inside on big one. name loop, hour loop, and wage loop, all of these need to go inside another loop that ask when you type done you exit the loop and go to the next step.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, and it isn't the same as the code you posted at all. Maybe you should edit your question to tell us more precisely what the assignment is?

Comment: I have updated code to reflect your program. Feel free to edit code to your logic.

Comment: would you use functions to do this same thing? I am not very familiar with them.  I also need to write out to a file  and read back into a list sorted lowest highest and average.

Answer (score 1):

A few errors as has been pointed out:

**In python, indentation decides the code blocks**

while loop:

```
while logic_test:
    # this is inside while loop
    ....
# this is outside while loop
```

**Certain functions on string does not replace the string in place, they return another string via return value**

upper:

```
>>> a = "done"
>>> a.upper()
'DONE'
>>> a
'done'
>>>
```

**Always initialize your variables.**

If you are using sequence methods, the variable should have been defined as sequence earlier.

```
>>> t.append('ll')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 't' is not defined
>>> t = []
>>> t.append('ll')
>>>
```

**Make your scope explicit**

```
lsthours = []
while len(eName)>0:
    ........
    lsthours.append(grossPay)
```